# How to send payments to my users using Coinbase API?

Tags: coinbase-api

I am able to receive payments using Coinbase Commerce API, but in my application I need to pay/send payments to my users too. Coinbase Commerce API do not offer this functionality, just checkout and charges to receive payments. How to sent payments using Coinbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coinbase offers a different API for its [Coinbase Pro](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/) and regular Coinbase services.

Coinbase Commerce's API does not support sending payments because Coinbase Commerce is not a vendor managed wallet (in that Coinbase does not have the keys). This means that Coinbase does not have the cryptographic authority to send funds, since this would reduce the security of the wallet.